# Расширение для Visual Studio 2013: подсветка фрагментов кода

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

Как подсветить (выделить цветом или подчеркнуть) нужные строки в коде? Дело в том, что тип создаваемого расширения VSpakage, примеры же с msdn имеют совсем другой тип проекта (тот же Classifier)
Дополнительная информация:

1. Пишу на C#
2. Надо чтобы нужные строки кода выделялись цветом (или еще как-то).
3. Интересует более простой способ выделения нужных фрагментов кода (без создания классификаторов, а просто по указанному тексту или номеру строки)